# Problem to edit polygon edge/vertex in Angular 6/7 using AGM

Tags: angular, google-maps, polygon

I'm working in a Angular proyect with polygon edition using AGM https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/index.html (my html code, below).
I can to get new coordinates to move one vertex with events (polyMouseDown and polyMouseUp) but, if I try to move one edge, the coordinates in polyMouseUp are not correct. I want to move one edge and get the coordinates for new vertex. Is there any way? or is it possible get all polygon coordinates?

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
     <agm-polygon [paths]="paths" [editable]=propertyEditPolygon
          (polyMouseDown)="polyMouseDown($event)"
          (polyMouseUp)="polyMouseUp($event)"
     >
     </agm-polygon>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue using polyline. When i move the edge i get wrong coordinates (?) or just not sure what are those coordinates should mean. anyway with polygon i think you can use getPath() https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmpolygon